# How can I store the conversation of LINE Bot using LINE API and HEROKU?

Tags: java, spring, heroku, line, filewriter

I created line bot using LINE API and HEROKU.
My bot works perfectly(echo example) but I wanna store the conversation with bot.
So I added the code using bufferedwriter and filewriter but txt file doesn't be created..

If I run my code on Spring boot app, the txt file created properly in the path. But if I run my code on Heroku, it doesn't.

what should I do?

Comment: If you get error messages or stacktrace, please add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another answer that tells you why this isn't working, but I want to point out that you shouldn't do it this way on Heroku. If you need to store data that is persistent, you should put it in a database. Heroku gives you a [free Postgres database](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql). Run the following command:

```
$ heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql
```

Then add the code that uses it by following the Heroku guide for [Connecting to Relational Databases](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java).

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Heroku doesn't have the directory of C drive. Can you try this?

```
String path = "test.txt";
```

You also need to replace `Path` with `path`

Comment: Heroku runs Linux, so there is no `C:` drive. But even if you write the file you won't be able to access it. The Heroku file system is ephemeral. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Comment: Then does it no way to store the conversation with bot?.. Or do I have to use db like mysql?

Comment: @J.Mi yes, you should use db